# Container Registry is missing from Packages & Registries in Gitlab

Tags: docker, gitlab

I'm new to the GitLab pipeline learning how to build docker images for projects using Gitlab Ci. However, I could not find the Container Registry to see the spaces for storing Docker images.
I don't have the Gitlab-runner installed yet so I don't know if this is the issue. Would please give some advice regarding this?

[image]

Comment: Maybe the container registry is not enabled (see [docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/packages/container_registry.html))? What version of GitLab are you using? 
You could also check if it's enabled in the project settings General > Visibility, project features, permissions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This means that the container registry is not enabled.

On self-hosted GitLab instances, an administrator must [configure and enable](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/packages/container_registry.html) the container registry feature.

On gitlab.com, the container registry is available by default.

Comment: it can be enabled, but broken on update as they change the syntax of gitlab.rb again and again.